# How can I calculate the sum of the column wise differences using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Despite using R and dplyr on a regular basis, I encountered the issue of not being able to calculate the sum of the absolute differences between all columns:

sum_diff=ABS(A-B)+ABS(B-C)+ABS(C-D)...

| A | B | C | D | sum_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |

I know I could iterate using a for loop over all columns, but given the size of my data frame, I prefer a more elegant and fast solution.

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dplyrs version of @akrun's elegant aproach that calculates the diff of the dataframe with it's shifted variant:

```
df %>%
  mutate(sum_diff = rowSums(abs(identity(.) %>% select(1:last_col(1)) 
                                - identity(.) %>% select(2:last_col()))))
```

And here we have the rowwise variant, which basicly follows the same idea but this time every row is used as a vector that get's substracted by it's shifted self.

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum_diff = map2_int(c_across(1:last_col(1)), 
                             c_across(2:last_col()), 
                             ~ abs(.x - .y)) %>% sum())
```

Answer (score 3):

We may remove the first and last columns, get the difference, and use `rowSums` on the `abs`olute values in `base R`.  This could be very efficient compared to a package solution

```
df1$sum_diff <- rowSums(abs(df1[-ncol(df1)] - df1[-1]))
```

-output

```
> df1
  A B C D sum_diff
1 1 2 3 4        3
2 2 1 3 4        4
3 1 2 1 1        2
4 4 1 2 1        5
```

---

Or another option is `rowDiffs` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowSums(abs(rowDiffs(as.matrix(df1))))
[1] 3 4 2 5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), B = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
    C = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L), D = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Daata from akrun (many thanks)!

This is complicated the idea is to generate a list of the combinations, I tried it with `combn` but then I get all possible combinations. So I created by hand.

With this combinations we then could use `purrr`s `map_dfc` and do some data wrangling after that:

```
library(tidyverse)

combinations <-list(c("A", "B"), c("B", "C"), c("C","D"))

purrr::map_dfc(combinations, ~{df <- tibble(a=data[[.[[1]]]]-data[[.[[2]]]]) 
names(df) <- paste0(.[[1]],"_v_",.[[2]])
df}) %>% 
  transmute(sum_diff = rowSums(abs(.))) %>% 
  bind_cols(data)
```

```
  sum_diff     A     B     C     D
     <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1        3     1     2     3     4
2        4     2     1     3     4
3        2     1     2     1     1
4        5     4     1     2     1
```

data:

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), B = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
    C = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L), D = c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```